# Problema con el escáner NFC en swift (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nfc, core

Tengo una clase para implementar el escáner NFC en mi aplicación. He visto varios tutoriales y bastante gente utiliza esta clase. El error que me devuelve es el siguiente: **Type 'DniNFCViewController' does not conform to protocol 'NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate'**. Este error me sugiere que añada nuevos métodos (en mi caso readerSession) pero ya los tengo añadidos. Sin embargo, he implementado esta misma clase en otro proyecto y me ha funcionado sin ningñun problema.

```
//
//  DniNFCViewController.swift
//  SSLSignature
//
//  Created by Ismael Márquez on 20/2/24.
//  Copyright © 2024 aralink. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreNFC

class DniNFCViewController: UIViewController, NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {
    
    var nfcSession: NFCNDEFReaderSession?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func startNFCSession(_ sender: Any) {
        nfcSession = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)
        nfcSession?.begin()
    }
    
    // MARK: - NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate
    
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print("Session invalidated with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
        // Handle NFC tag detection here
        for message in messages {
            for record in message.records {
                // Process NDEF records
                // This is where you would handle the data read from the NFC tag
                print("Record payload: \(record.payload)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que alguien haya resuelto mi problema antes y me pueda ayudar a solucionarlo y explicarme por qué sucede.

Comment: Y si utilizas los métodos que se auto genera en el error? Y agregas el código en esos métodos se soluciona? Puede ser que no sean los mismos métodos, algo debe ser diferente que por eso te muestra que debas añadirlos.

Comment: se me generan los métodos pero luego el método: `func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error)` se genera una y otra vez aunque ya lo tengo implementado.

Comment: Agregué todo tu código y no tengo el error que mencionas; de igual manera eliminé los métodos del protocolo y les agregué al marcar el error y funciona bien. Lo único que queda es que el nombre de la clase `DniNFCViewController` esté duplicado.